# trouble importing Pytorch in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pytorch

Iam new to deep learning and Iam trying to import Pytorch on Jupyter Notebook.
I installed Pytorch with the following lines of code in Anaconda Prompt.

```
conda create -n pytorch_p37 python=3.7
conda activate pytorch_p37
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
conda install jupyter
conda list
```

it all executed well.
but on importing pytorch it shows errors.

```
import torch
```

this error below:-

```
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

[error showing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Kuf.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lied where I was installing a CUDA version.
I tried installing the CPU version and it worked fine (CUDA None).

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

Answer (score 1):

```
!pip install torch
```

It worked for me in a Anaconda's Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I lost one hour and found that launching the conda environment as stacked version does not lead to error:

in your example:

```
conda activate pytorch_p37
```

and from jupyter

```
import torch  # error
```

from terminal:

```
conda activate --stack pytorch_p37
```

and from jupyter:

```
import torch  # success
```

I could not figure out why :/

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment